# Are self pollinated plants genetically different?

Tags: pollination

Gametes in pollen grain are formed during meiosis in the anther. And meiosis produces genetically different gametes. When the pollens grains are carried to the stigma to fertilise the egg cell of the different/same flower from the **same** plant, doesn't it produce genetically different flowers even though it is self pollinating because of the variation in gametes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

In Meiosis there is genetic recombination (by recombinase) in the Meiosis-1. So even though it is self pollination, there is significant genetic variation.
Still for higher degree of variation cross pollination is exhibited.

It should be noted that cross pollination has greater evolutionary significance.

Few plants exhibit self-incompatibility to supress self pollination (in monoecious flowers/plants).